# path to css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

My static generated jekyll website lies at  `/var/www/myname`

With apache mapping this website is accessible at `mycompany.com/myname`

Now in my _layouts folder I have a template common to all which includes the header and footer.

This template uses css and JS files in the folders `/var/www/myname/css` and `/var/www/myname/js` like this

```
src = "js/myscript.js"
src = "css/style.css"
```

This works fine for `/var/www/myname/index.html`

Now I have created another static page at `/var/www/myname/about/index.html` which uses the same template.

But when I try to access this at `mycompany.com/myname/about` my css and JS are not loaded as in the error their src is reported as `/var/www/myname/about/css/style.css` and `/var/www/myname/about/js/myscript.js`

So what path should I use for them in my template ?
If I name them like this

```
   src = "/js/myscript.js"
    src = "/css/style.css"
```

then they are searched at `mycompany.com/js` and `mycompany.com/css`

Comment: what about `/myname/js/myscript.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template file is being called form different locations causing the relative path to be to a different place. Using absolute paths here would fix that:

```
src = "mycompany.com/myname/js/myscript.js"
src = "mycompany.com/myname/css/style.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths like `/myname/js/myscript.js` or `http://www.mycompany.com/myname/js/myscript.js`

If you use absolute paths, the relative path of the calling page doesn't matter.